# How to add an unit to a calculated value properly?

Tags: lengths, units, fp

I have some trouble to understand how I ought to handle some values I calculated with [fp](https://ctan.org/pkg/fp) to use them as length. It is obvious that I have to add an unit to the number to use it, but trying to do so, I get one of the following errors:

```
Missing number, treated as zero
```

or

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
```

Here is, what I am trying to do:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\stripPT[1]{\strip@pt#1}
\makeatother
\newcommand\addPT[1]{{#1}pt}
\newcommand{\setImageToGrid}[2]{%
  \FPmul\xyz{12}{20}%
  \FPdiv\xyz{\xyz{}}{\stripPT{\onelineskip}}%
  \FPclip\xyz{\xyz}%
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim={0 \addPT{\xyz} 0 \addPT{\xyz}},%
     clip, height=\xyz]{#1}
      \legend{#2}
  \end{figure}
}
```

(The calculation does not make sense, it's only for testing.) The only workaround I found so fare is to do something like this `\xyz\onelineskip`, of course I would have to divide the `\xyz` by `\onelineskip` before to get the correct value. But there must be a cleaner way. I also tried to save the value to a custom length before using it, but then I get the same problem there. As there are no types in LaTeX I am stuck.

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\stripPT[1]{\strip@pt#1}
\makeatother
\newcommand\addPT[1]{{#1}pt}

% Create and save the box.
\newsavebox{\Image}
\newlength{\imageh}

\newcommand{\setImageToGrid}[2]{
  \FPmul\xyz{12}{20}
  \FPdiv\xyz{\xyz{}}{\stripPT{\onelineskip}}
  \FPclip\xyz{\xyz}
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim={0 \addPT{\xyz} 0 \addPT{\xyz}},%
     clip, height=\xyz]{#1}
      \legend{#2}
  \end{figure}
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\newpage
\setImageToGrid{some.png}{Something}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

UPDATE: I added some `%` to the example as suggested in some comments.

Comment: You have to remove the braces from your `\addPT` command: `\newcommand\addPT[1]{#1 pt}`. You also have to `\addPT` in the `height` argument: `clip, height=\addPT{\xyz}]{#1}`.

Comment: unrelated but you need several `%` at ends of lines to avoid generating unwanted white space.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, that's it. But why? I thought I have to avoid a white space. And how would I notate this, without declaring an extra command? (The different treatment of the height was only for testing).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing this out. I'm using `%` in the original context.

Comment: The whitespace is automatically ignored after a control sequence.

Comment: @TeXnician yes but `\setImageToGrid`  adds 5 space tokens in addition to the figure float every time it is used. (depending where it is used that may or may not affect the output)

Comment: @user5950 When you pass a control sequence as argument to another macro, it doesn't matter if you use `#1pt` or `#1 pt` because the text `#1` already got tokenized as a parameter and the replacement (here the control sequence `\xyz`) also got tokenized as a control sequence, so TeX will know that `#1pt` becomes `\xyz pt`. The braces you added, on the other hand, will confuse TeX because it will look for a number but it will find a `{` (thus "missing number"). You get the same effect if you try to do `\parskip = {10} pt`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach using expl3 (the code is not that idiomatic, but it does the job and you do not have to care about spaces). It evaluates only once (as you do not pass any parameters).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\edef\mycalcres{ \dim_eval:n { \fp_eval:n { floor((12*20)/\strip@pt\onelineskip) } pt } }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setImageToGrid}[2]{
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim={0 \mycalcres{} 0 \mycalcres},%
     clip, height=\mycalcres]{#1}
      \legend{#2}
  \end{figure}
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\newpage
\setImageToGrid{example-image-duck.pdf}{Something}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```